# Can't reproduce crash that occurred during App Store review [locale issue]

Tags: objective-c, ios, local

I have just received a crash log from Apple after my update being rejected.

After reviewing the crash log I have found the offending code, which was related to parsing a date.

When I run this app on my device I do not get this error. I have a feeling that it is an issue with the Local of the device that Apple is testing on.

During my run, the `original` string below resolved to `2012-12-04T11:02:29.5600000+0000`. I'm just wondering what other ways it could appear if in a different Locale.

**More importantly, how can in test my app in the same environment as Apple so I don't need to wait out the review process to test**

Note: I inherited this code, so any suggestions on improving the date parsing function would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

The crash came from the call `[original substringToIndex:range.location+3]` in the following function.

```
+(NSString*)convertDate:(NSDate*)date withFormatter:(NSDateFormatter*)dateFormatter{

    NSString *original = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSRange range = [original rangeOfString:@"+"];
    NSString *substring = [original substringToIndex:range.location+3];
    NSString *substring2 = [original substringFromIndex:range.location+3];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",substring,@":",substring2];
}
```

The call to this function is made in the following context

```
NSDate *timestamp = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [DateHelper convertDate:timestamp withFormatter:UTCDateFormatter];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible that saying +3 is causing there to be an out of bounds range exception. Have you tested that using the [NSDate date] will return the same format in other timezones?

Either way you should be checking two things at a minimum - then parse the method multiple date types to confirm that the app will still function:

1. that the range from the following line has a location:

   ```
   NSRange range = [original rangeOfString:@"+"];
   if (range.location != NSNotFound)
   {
       //do stuff here
   }
   ```
2. That the range.location + the 3 you are putting in does not exceed the total string length

   ```
   NSRange range = [original rangeOfString:@"+"];
   if (range.location != NSNotFound)
   {
      if ((range.location + 3) <= original.length)
      {
          //you should also check that ((range.location + 3) + range.length) <= original.length as well
          //do stuff here
      }
   }
   ```

while the above does not really solve the issue of potentially displaying incorrect dates/timestamps - it should prevent the application from attempting to seek a range or index out of the bounds of the string length

Hope this helps,

Comment: It turns out the *original string contained an ISO8601 datetime string. So I just returned that and all was good. Btw, it was an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter will format your date using your device date format and timezone.

```
// Convert the date to current time zone    
    NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = sourceGMTOffset - destinationGMTOffset;

    NSDate *destinationDateHere1 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:yourDate];
```